# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException при попытке использования getLocalHost()

Tags: java, android, сокет, клиент-сервер

Занимаюсь созданием клиент-сервера на сокетах при помощи java, с той особенностью, что в моем случае клиентом выступает приложение написанное на android.
И если с сервером все хорошо(проверял его работу через telnet), то с клиентом выходят большие проблемы.
При попытке получить локальный хост: 
 `InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();` 
Выдает следующую ошибку(если через try-catch попросить вывести в лог):

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Подключал работу с сетью в манифест-файл, но не помогло:
 `< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
Перерыл форумы, но подобной проблемы не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь сюда:)

Comment: Google выдаёт 60 900 страниц по запросу "NetworkOnMainThreadException", в том числе ссылку на официальную документацию. Конкретно на ruSO поиск выдаёт по тому же запросу 32 результата.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код ошибки сам за себя говорит - нельзя использовать в главном потоке работу с сетью.

Вы можете запустить в отдельном потоке используя Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try  {
            //ваш код работы с сетью
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

Можете разрешить работу в основном потоке (категорически не рекомендуется):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Можете использовать `AsyncTask`:

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected RSSFeed doInBackground(Void... void) {
        try {
            //ваш код работы с сетью
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;

            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
        // здесь можете обрабатывать ошибки при работе с сетью
    }
}
```

1. Про `AsyncTask` по-русски: [Класс AsyncTask](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php)
2. О `Thread` по-русски: [Потоки. Класс Thread и интерфейс Runnable](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/thread.php)

Comment: а если в разных методах нужно обращаться к серверу(например, при нажатии на кнопку, нужно отправить информацию из формы)?

Comment: @nrjshka можете создать `AsyncTask` потока соединения и отсылки данных, другой `AsyncTask` соединения и получения данных. Можете написать уникальный `AsyncTask` / `Service` для этих дейтвий с обработкой всех вариантов параметров)) Если интересует последний вариант - у меня есть самописный `Service` с `BroadcastReceiver` которые соединяются с SQL сервером, выполняют нужную залачу вставки/изменения/удаления/получения данных и возвращают результат... Но там замудрено сделано))

Comment: А больше альтернатив нет?
Нужно обращаться к серверу в N-местах и вообще не понятно как это можно реализовать:D

Comment: @nrjshka можно сделать через `Service` - на мой взгляд самый лучший вариант, хотя я чаще для простых задач использую `AsyncTask`. О сервисах по русски: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php  А по поводу N мест не парьтесь - поток отработал и умер, вы же не паритесь когда String используете в 20 местах класса))

Comment: Согласен, но я использую это на клиенте и мне нужно обращаться к серверу постоянно, без отключений

Comment: а есть пример работы AsyncTask с сетью(и если есть, то желательно еще и с android:) )?

Comment: @nrjshka скачка html-документа из инета пойдет?

Comment: нууу, можно:D
вообще, желательно, работу с сокетами, но это тоже нормально:)

Comment: просто, проблема в том, что нужно иметь постоянное подключение, а не кратковременное

Comment: @nrjshka тогда `Service` -однозначно, он организует долгоживущий поток где можно хранить соединение и обращаться через соединение куда надо.

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, `у меня есть самописный Service с BroadcastReceiver` – а в каком момент Вы делаете анрегистр броадкастресивера?

Comment: @post_zeew сейчас проект подгружу - уточню, ибо писал еще в январе

Comment: @post_zeew на `onResume` регистрировался, на `onDestroy` разрегивал, причем методы рега и разрега дергались из самого ресивера. могу скинуть линк на проект на гите - один фиг это был курсач жены)

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, `onDestroy()` может не вызваться, поэтому анрегистр нужно делать раньше. С другой стороны, если анрегистр делать раньше, то в фоне Вы не получите броадкаст. Было интересно, как Вы решали эту проблему.

Comment: @post_zeew по сути уровень курсача - ни разу не ловил ошибок, а если подумать - ну перенести в `onPause`...

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, `если анрегистр делать раньше, то в фоне Вы не получите броадкаст.`

Comment: @post_zeew а у меня он в фоне и не юзался))) сугубо подключение-работа с данными-отключение-отправка результата.

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, Если во время работы приложения, например, поступит входящий звонок, а броадкаст уйдет в это время, то аналогично он не дойдет до туда, где его ждут.

Answer (score -1):

Из основного потока нельзя отправлять запросы. Только через AsyncTask, как сказано выше :)

Comment: Абсолютно не только через `AsyncTask`. Даже скорее через него, в большинстве случаев, не рекомендуется, из за возможных утечек памяти по незнанию.